# How can I add "item" to arraylist, if checkbox is marked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm still kinda new into c#, and I'm currently stucked in a project. So basically I've currently have a form consisting of 5 textboxes, one checkbox and a button. When the user fills in the information, and submitting without marking the checkbox, the information is stored in a arraylist. If the user signs up as a traindriver, and marks the traindriver checkbox and submits, then a "id" need to be passed in to the arraylist, aswell as all the other information like first name and last name etc.

Currently I have a person class, which works just fine. Then I have a subclass called traindrivers, which one consists of a "id" variable, that "increments" every time a new traindrivers is signed up, since they can't have the same number. So how can I add this "id" to the "personsArrayList" if the person that are signed up, are marked as a traindriver?

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbKgw.png)

I've tried to use the procedure as I've used when new Persons are added. But for some reason, I couldn't find the varaibles which contains the id.

```
public class Persons
{
    //instance variables
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
    private string email;
    private int age;


    //constructor
    public Persons(string firstname, string lastname, string email, int age)
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set { firstname = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value; }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName + " - " + Email + " - " + Age + ".";
    }

}

public class Traindrivers : Persons
{
    protected int id;
    protected static int mycounter;

    public Traindrivers(int id, string firstname, string lastname, string email, int age) : base(firstname, lastname, email, age)
    {
        mycounter++;
        id = mycounter;
    }


    public int LicensNumber
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return LicensNumber + FirstName + LastName + Email + Age;
    }
}
```

----------- aspx page ---------

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Persons p1 = new Persons(TextBoxFirstName.Text, TextBoxLastName.Text, TextBoxEmail.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxAge.Text));
        personsArrayList.Add(p1);

        //Session["trainpersons"] = personsArrayList;
    }

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // When the checkbox is marked, add "id" to the arraylist
    }

    protected void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < personsArrayList.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(personsArrayList[i].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}

protected void trainBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < traindriversArrayList.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(traindriversArrayList[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

The expected result is to add "id" whenever is it a traindriver, that signs up. And it is of course expected to go into the personsArrayList.

Comment: you should check if that checkbox is checked or not when you click that button. if it is checked then you pass the id, else the same code you already have in click

Comment: @phalanx So, i should make a if statements that checks, if the checkbox is checked inside the button click? Which parameters are then going into the traindrivers when they are made? Only the id or all the information?

Comment: well, you said traindriver is a subclass, I think you want it to inherit from the person. if it is right, then you should first work on the inheritance, then you need new ArrayList for traindrivers

Comment: Ahh alright. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @phalanx So now I've inherit the person class. But I have a hard time figuering out, how I can get this "id" in, when the new objects are made? When normal persons are made as objects, it catches the passed in information in the textboxes. But now its an id, which should increment by one everytime a new traindriver is made.

Comment: update your post then to see what is going on and help you with the solution

Comment: @phalanx I have updated the traindrivers class with the inheritance

Comment: as a bonus for a better result, try to format your ToString method with spaces and maybe columns to show better strings.@Vibi97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok based on this new edit, everything will be ok with few minor changes.
first of all you do not need any counter, static id will be enough and because you want to increment that id, it should be initialized. and since it is going to work automatically, no need to take id as an argument

```
    public class Traindrivers : Persons
    {
        protected int id=0;
    //                   ^^
        protected static int mycounter=0;

        public Traindrivers(/*int id,*/ string firstname, string lastname, string email, int age) : base(firstname, lastname, email, age)
//                          ^^^^^^^^^
        {
            mycounter++;
            id = mycounter;
        }


        public int LicensNumber
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return LicensNumber + FirstName + LastName + Email + Age;
        }
    }
```

when you want to use it, in Button1_Click method, first you check if that checkbox is checked or not, then behave based on that, like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(CheckBox1.checked==true){//information is about a traindriver
            Traindrivers t1 = new Traindrivers (TextBoxFirstName.Text, TextBoxLastName.Text, TextBoxEmail.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxAge.Text));
            traindriversArrayList.Add(t1);
    }
    else{//information in textboxes is not about traindriver
            Persons p1 = new Persons(TextBoxFirstName.Text, TextBoxLastName.Text, TextBoxEmail.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxAge.Text));
            personsArrayList.Add(p1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem now is that, whenever I choose to sign up another Traindriver, all the existing traindrivers gets the same id. So basically every traindrivers is getting the save id. ^^ But it's close. I do really appreciate the help :)

Comment: yes you are right, maybe you still need that counter, i will edit my answer

Comment: Nevermind. I made a minor mistake. Thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: Still having some troubles unfortunately. It seems like it still changes all the traindrivers to have the same id for some reason... Currently I'm listing out the information in a normal listbox, just to see the results. It's done by a normal for loop. But yeah, it does change the id for all the traindrivers. I don't know if it is my for loop you causes this problem. I have updated my post, so you can see it if you want to